# height="100%" on iframe inside a flex-child doesn't work in Safari

Tags: css, iframe, safari, flexbox

Why `height="100%"` on the `<iframe>` has no effect in Safari, and how would you fix this?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.name {
  line-height: 32px;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. */
  border: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="name">My iframe</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: add display:flex and to flex-grow and remove the height:100%